# wpf xaml combobox bound to integer data

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a database table that includes a gender column as in `int` (1=Male, 2=Female).

I wish to declare a `ComboBox` in the xaml that binds to the column but shows Male and Female.

What is the equivalent to Value in each `ComboBoxItem`?

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male" value=1 />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Female" value=2 />
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want. Here are a couple. Pick whichever suits you.

**1. Use a Value Converter**

Set up your combo box like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Gender, Converter={x:Static local:GenderConverter.Instance}}" />
```

In the viewmodel:

```
// Hook up to your data however you want
public int Gender
{
    get { return _gender; }
    set
    {
        if (_gender != value)
        {
            _gender = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private int _gender;

// Initialize to ["Male", "Female"]
public string[] Genders { get; private set; }
```

And the converter:

```
internal class GenderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static GenderConverter Instance { get; private set; }

    static GenderConverter()
    {
        Instance = new GenderConverter();
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1: return "Male";
                case 2: return "Female";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string gender = (string)value;
            if (string.Compare(gender, "Male", true) == 0) return 1;
            if (string.Compare(gender, "Female", true) == 0) return 2;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2. Convert the Value in ViewModel**

Set up your combo box like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Gender}" />
```

In the viewmodel:

```
// Hook up to your data however you want
public string Gender
{
    get
    {
        switch(_gender)
        {
            case 1: return "Male";
            case 2: return "Female";
            default: return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        int actualValue = 0;
        if (string.Compare(value, "Male", true) == 0) actualValue = 1;
        if (string.Compare(value, "Female", true) == 0) actualValue = 2;
        if (_gender != actualValue)
        {
            _gender = actualValue;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private int _gender;

// Initialize to ["Male", "Female"]
public string[] Genders { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Blimey.  If I have a separate table in the database I can bind the items source to that much easier `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=DataContext.GendersTable}" DisplayMemberPath="Gender" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding GenderID}" />`.  It just clutters up my database with a table with 2 rows and 2 columns that will never change...